# Shiny R: call to a server output using a function

Tags: r, parsing, server, shiny

I am new in R and Shiny and just started to learn developing/coding. I am trying to use a function to call an output object in the server part. My goal is to use the function many times by passing different inputs.
The server output should look like this (very much simplified):

```
output$Euro <- DT::renderDT(
  NV_Euro()
)
```

And the function to parse the output looks like this  (the input EuroTab below is a data frame):

```
server_Output <- function(EuroTab){                   
                    output$Euro <- DT::renderDT(
                      EuroTab
                 )
```

So that i can use the function to parse the output object in the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
          server_Output('NV_Euro')
}
```

To get:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
              output$Euro <- DT::renderDT(
                              NV_Euro()
                             )
}
```

But this doesn't work. Would be grateful if anyone could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but your `output` always needs unique IDs. If you take this into account, you can create something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  DT::DTOutput("mytable1"),
  DT::DTOutput("mytable2")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Your function
  myfunction <- function(data, name) {
    
    output[[name]] <- DT::renderDT(
      data
    )
    
  }
  
  #Data Table 1 Output
  myfunction(iris, "mytable1")
  
  #Data Table 2 Output
  myfunction(mtcars, "mytable2")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit

Yes, it is possible to use reactives. Note that I pass the unevaluated reactive to the function and only in the function itself evaluate it (by adding the brackets):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num_row", "max. # of rows",
               value = min(c(nrow(mtcars), nrow(iris))),
               max = min(c(nrow(mtcars), nrow(iris)))),
  DT::DTOutput("mytable1"),
  DT::DTOutput("mytable2")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Your function
  myfunction <- function(data_input, name) {
    
    output[[name]] <- DT::renderDT(
      data_input()
    )
    
  }
  
  my_data_1 <- reactive({
    iris[seq_len(input$num_row), ]
  })
  
  #Data Table 1 Output
  myfunction(my_data_1, "mytable1")
  
  my_data_2 <- reactive({
    mtcars[seq_len(input$num_row), ]
  })
  
  #Data Table 2 Output
  myfunction(my_data_2, "mytable2")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot starja. I checked the code and it works. However there is another problem i did not realize it will occur. The data frame input, iris or mtcars in your example is a reactiveFileReader in my case. I noticed that when something change in the input the ui does not react at all.. is there something like a reactive output you can use in this way that will fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to make sure where to evaluate your `reactive`s, see my edit.

Comment: Great, it's working!  I was indeed struggling with when and where to add the brackets. It looks like i need to further dig this matter .. Many thanks Starja!

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer is useful for you, please consider accepting it

Comment: Done! sorry i am new at stack overflow, did not know the features very well yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, we can use a function inside shiny and call it from multiple places.

The below minimal example shows a single function being called by two data tables. With the function parameter deciding which table to display.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    tableOutput("mytable1"),
    tableOutput("mytable2")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    #Your function
    myfunction <- function(str_table_selected) {
        
        if(str_table_selected == "iris")   {return(head(iris, 10))}
        if(str_table_selected == "mtcars") {return(head(mtcars, 10))}
        
    }
    
    #Data Table 1 Output
    output$mytable1 <- renderTable(
        
        myfunction("iris")
        
    )
    
    #Data Table 2 Output
    output$mytable2 <- renderTable(
        
        myfunction("mtcars")
        
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks a lot for your answer.  However i need slightly different thing.  The call should be like this:  `server <- function(input, output, session)  {    server_Output('NV_Euro')     }`    to get this inside the server part:  `server <- function(input, output, session)    { output$Euro <- DT::renderDT( NV_Euro() )   }`  Probably is this more parsing?  Sorry, i can't get line breaks in this comment ..